# Razor pages bind html element attribute to model property

Tags: razor-pages

I failed to find a way for changing html element background color according to the model entity state property (active will be green, not active red ....). The easiest procedure I thought about is to bind those 2 attribute/property one in the view and other in module, like I used to do in WPF. But unfortunately I failed to find any simple reference how to do it.

cshtml:

```html
<div class=" mybox" style="background-color:@contact.color">
                        <label asp-for="@contact.Name"></label>
                        <label>@contact.Status</label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: need to see more of your code, top of cshtml and .cs associated please

Comment: contact is a model, then I know to bind Name and Status properties and show it in the label. the question is how can I bind style background color to color property?

Comment: actually I found something [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685710/div-color-in-razor-view) it's not exactly what I expected but it gave me another conceptual solution. just need to define appropriate style according to the state property in model.